# Homeomorphic sets

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently doing an introduction course in Topology and Geometry. I came across the following proposition I have a few 'beginner-questions' on.

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have a few questions about this proposition.

"$U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$" What exactly does it mean? I thought being homeomorphic refers to a map. Does it mean that there exists a map from U to R^n which is homeomorphic? Also, since $U$ is a subset of R^n is it not trivial that it is homeomorphic (ie. has the same structure) to R^n?

Comment: Perhaps it's a linguistic matter. In English there is no adjective to indicate the property of "being a homeomorph*ism*": you just say that "the map $f$ is a homeomorphism". "Homeomorph*ic*" is referred to topological spaces, specifically: $$\text{Two topological spaces } X,\,Y\text{ are homeomorphic}\\ \text{if and only if there is a homeomorphism }f:X\to Y$$
In your case, the topology on $U$ is the subspace topology.

Comment: Also if $U$ is any subset of $\mathbb R^n$ it does not have necessarily to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ for example take an open non simply connected region (like an open annulus).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Just what I needed.